# Best Algorithm to find intersection between 2 Intervals

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I have a table in the database called Control:

Table structure:

> **Id | Name | MinValue (decimal) | MaxValue(decimal)**

I have some restrictions on that table, one of it's restrictions is :   ***no intersections***.

*Example* : if the table has some values as follows:

> row1 : 1 | Test1 | 1.3 | 2.5  //***valid***
>   row2 : 2 | Test2 | 3.3 | 4.5  // ***valid***
>   row3 : 3 | Test3 | 5   | 6    // ***valid***

Now if I want to add a new record, it must not intersect with any other row

*Example*:

> row4 : 4 | Test4 | 5.1 | 10  //***not valid*** since slot from 5 to 6 is reserved
>   row5 : 5 | Test5 | 1.0 | 1.4 // ***not valid*** since slot from 1.3 to 2.5 is reserved

I'm using this code, and it worked perfectly, but I wonder if there is a better solution and more efficient :

```
var allRows = db.Control.ToList();
var minValue = control.MinimumValue;
var maxValue = control.MaximumValue;
bool flag = true;
foreach(var row in allRows)
{
    for(var i = minValue; i <= maxValue && flag ; i = decimal.Add( i , (decimal) 0.01))
    {
        if(i >= row.MinimumValue && i <= row.MaximumValue)
        {
            flag = false;
            min = row.MinimumValue;
            max = row.MaximumValue;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (flag)
{
    //add
}
else
{
    //intersection
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: There is no such thing as "intersection between two points".  A point is pretty much the only geometrical concept that cannot intersect with another.

Comment: There is no point to the inner loop, there is overlap if minValue < row.maxValue or maxValue > row.minValue.  Turns it from O(n*m) to O(n).  You can further optimize it to O(log(n)) with a SortedList.

Comment: didn't work , @HansPassant

Comment: Thanks for clarification @MikeNakis

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a `O(LogN)` issue...

Keep segments Ordered by their Start Value.
in a valid list `s[i].end < s[i+1].start` for any `i`

when inserting new segment, find it's position (the one that which start is closest (but lesser) than your new segment) call it `i`

```
if((seg[i-1].end < new.start) && (seg[i+1].start > new.end)) 
    //OK to insert
else
    // intersect
```

Comment: I didn't understand your statement "Keep segments by their Start value"  
what did you meant by segment ? does it contain the decimal value ?

Comment: added "Ordered by" to clarify my intent. thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume this is the object you're trying to add :

```
var control = new Control()
{
    Name = 'name',
    MinValue = 5,
    MaxValue = 6
};
```

You can do the following:

```
var biggerThanMinValue = db.Control.Count(x => x.MinValue >= control.MinValue) != 0;
var biggerThanMaxValue = db.Control.Count(x => x.MaxValue >= control.MaxValue) != 0;
if (!biggerThanMinValue && !biggerThanMinValue)
{
    db.Control.Add(control); // or whatever your add operation is
}
```

By doing so you:

- do NOT load the whole table in-memory -> performance gain terms of time, traffic and memory
- let the database use it's data structures/algorithms to verify that the item can be added (the db should be able to optimize this request) -> another performance gain (cpu + time)
- have clearer backend code
- have less code to test

Edit: I suppose you could also ask the database to sort your table by min/max value and then make some validation (1 or 2 ifs), but the first approach is better, imo.

Comment: didn't work, doesn't catch all cases :
ex :
if the table contains minValue=7 and maxValue=9
and I want to add  minValue = 10 and maxValue = 12

what happens according to your solution ?